# cakephp update a record in a different model / table

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am in a Model1 (Model1)and I need to run some business logic that should update a record in the Model2 (table2).
Here is the query/action I need to run from Model1 in Model2

```
$sql ="update table2 SET products = $product  WHERE `id` = '".$id."'";
```

How would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two models are related, you can save data to two tables at the same time. See the book for information on how to use [`Model::saveAll()`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data). This is how you would represent that query though:

```
$this->Model2->id = $id;
$this->Model2->saveField('products', $product);
```

Answer (score 1):

if the 2 models are not related (no relationship), Model->query() is a quick and dirty way. Otherwise, if Model1 has a relationship to Model2, in Model1, you can refer to Model2 by : `$this->Model2->function_you_need_to_call()`